# How to write config file for eslint stylish mode?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, eslint

I'm using Eslint for a react application. This is a part of my webpack config:

```js
{
    enforce: 'pre',
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    loader: 'eslint-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    options: {
      formatter: require('eslint/lib/cli-engine/formatters/stylish'),
    }
},
{
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    use: 'babel-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules/
}
```

I've set stylish as formatter, but when I start my application I get this error :

`ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
Error: No ESLint configuration found in D:\react\src.`

But apparently stylish is default mode of eslint, but I should create config file ?

What I should write into config file ?

Thanks

Comment: eslint is separate from webpack. It requires an `.eslintrc` file.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with webpack. Webpack can run eslint as part of the build process to do some logic related to linting, but eslint is a separate program.

As such, it requires its own configuration. Its configuration is in a file called `.eslintrc`.

Here's how to configure it: [Configuring ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring)

Comment: I've created an empty .eslintrc file in root path and that works right.

Comment: Good on you. :)

Comment: But I've this error :

`ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

D:\react\src\index.js
  1:1  error  Parsing error: The keyword 'import' is reserved

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)`

Is this a normal error view ?

Comment: Configure ESLint properly. Looks like it's using a configuration in which `import` is unusable in this context.

Comment: But It points to a simple import : `import React from 'react';`

Comment: `import` wasn't a thing until a particular ecmascript version.

Comment: I've installed `babel-eslint` and that solved with this config for eslint `{
  "parser": "babel-eslint"
}
`